# How can I split github repo into two?

Tags: git, github, git-filter-repo

I have github repo with 2 folders: client/server. I need to make separate repositories from these folders, but so that the commit history for each repository is not lost. After that, the main repository must be deleted. I came across the filter-repo utility on the Internet, but I didn't really figure out how it works. Could you help with that?

MAIN-REPO:

```
.git
  client
  server
```

expected result:

```
client:
    .git

  server:
    .git
```

thx!

Comment: why dont you create 2 different repo and add that as the remote of this local branch and push it up. And then delete the unwanted file from both the repos

Comment: @so-random-dude, cuz I wanna to setup github-actions differently for these 2 repositories

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-filter-repo%5D+split

Comment: "[Using git subtree to split a repository](https://lostechies.com/johnteague/2014/04/04/using-git-subtrees-to-split-a-repository/)"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+split+repository+in+two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `subtree split`

##### TL;DR;

`subtree split` will "split" your content into branches

#### Long answer

- Split the main branch (whole content) by "folders" into branches.
- Create submodules from the new branches (add,commit & push) into new git repo

#### How?

`git subtree split <path> -b <branch>` and then add remote for each submodule and push the branch to the remote.

```bash
# split the "main repo" into branches and preserve full history
git subtree split -P client -b <client>
git subtree split -P server -b <server>

# For each branch that you extract client/server
# create a git repo (which will be used for submodules)

# Add the content to the git server
# add remote for client
git remote add submodule1 <client_url>

# push the submodule
git push submodule1 <branch>
```

- Once you have all your submodules set up add them to the "main" repo

```bash
# Add the submodules 
git submodule add <url>
```

Once all your submodules are added commit the `.gitmodules` file